# Какую функцию использовать?

Tags: c, linux

Как я понял в модуле ядра нет ptrace, но мне нужен ptrace для трассировки процесса
если не ptrace, то какую функцию использовать для модуля ядра?

Comment: Вы хотите трассировать процесс из модуля ядра ? Зачем так сложно ?

Comment: ну вот мне по заданию это нужно

Comment: Насколько помню Ваш предылущий вопрос на эту тему, там о трассировке речь не шла. 

Вы весь текст задания лучше опубликуйте.

Comment: Написать драйвер, осуществляющий поиск в памяти указанного по имени процесса указанной при загрузке строки. В случае обнаружения драйвер должен сохранить следующую за обнаруженной строку в файл. Искомая строка и имя процесса указываются при загрузке драйвера.

Answer (score 3):

ptrace() это системный вызов. Он реализован именно в ядре. Тщательней изучайте код ядра.

**Update** на основе комментария о задании.

Сразу предупреждаю, исходник ядра Линукса никогда не читал, так что советы скорее гипотетические.

1) В ядре должен быть список процессов, скорее всего это список блоков управления процессом (назовем PCB). Ваша задача найти его и научиться перемещаться по нему (последовательно перебирать PCB).

2) В PCB должна быть ссылка на аргументы командной строки (видимо это то иия, которое Вам задано).

3) В PCB должна быть ссылка на карту памяти процесса (соответствие виртуальных адресов процесса физическим страницам памяти). Тут Вы ищете заданную строку. Вы должны просматривать ее (карту памяти процесса) и делать "ремаппинг", отображая какую-то Вашу страницу (скорее пару страниц т.к. граница страницы может оказаться внутри искомой строки)  на физические страницы процесса (для этого в ядре наверняка есть функции, модифицирующие MMU).

***Видимо самое сложное*** это синхронизация работы Вашего модуля с остальной системой. Можно (хотя наверняка очень плохо) запретить прерывания, **но** что делать если страница не подгружена в ОЗУ ?

Вобщем тут надо серьезно разбираться. Действительно, можно посмотреть, что делает код системного вызова ptrace() при запросе чтения адреса (трассировка здесь ни при чем (просто название к него такое)).

Успехов !

Comment: ну, а как? это сделать? (((( подскажите пожалуйста реализацию!!!
а именно какую библиотеку подключать и хотя бы пример кода! Очень прошу!

Comment: @Дмитрий, Вы извините, но вот у меня сейчас нет возможности погрузиться в исходники Линукса.

Comment: ну, а хотя бы какую подключить нужно библиотеку подскажите пожалуйста!
sys/ptrace.h
linux/ptrace.h
не работают

Comment: ptrace для модуля ядра? По-моему Вы хотите странного. Весьма странного. Посмотрите, например, сюда http://wiki.opennet.ru/Linux_kernel_debug

Comment: спасибо большое за объяснение!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, Вам нужно сначала вообще разобраться с устройством ядра и принципами написания модулей. Почитайте какие-нибудь книжки по этой теме и параллельно изучайте исходники. По-моему, Вы просто не очень хорошо представляете всю картину.

Comment: да причем тут знаю, не знаю, если эта функция не запускается совсем никак, в инете я находил исходники для ptrace но чисто на уровне пользовательских программ, а не для модуля(((

Comment: И это естественно. Не могли бы Вы написать, откуда такие странные идеи? (Типа вытаскивания себя из болота за волосы наподобие б. Мюнхаузена)

Comment: задание для лабораторной

Comment: Вы уверены, что в формулировке задания нет ошибки? Потому что объяснения, как работает ptrace, и почему её нельзя использовать для компонент ядра, вероятно выходят за рамки лабораторных. (Возможно под модулем в задании понимается не модуль ядра -- это вполне определённый термин, а что-то другое)

Comment: написать драйвер ............................

Comment: Чудесно. А причём тут ptrace?

Comment: находим процесс, находим его границы памяти, затем ищем в памяти строку(для этого и нужен ptrace)

Comment: Ну @avp уже написал план работ. А ptrace позволяет пользовательскому процессу получать доступ (среди прочего) к памяти и регистрам **дочернего** процесса. @avp рекомендует смотреть реализацию ptrace,  одно замечание: функциональность большая, а времени на всё мало. Что касается отсутствия страницы в памяти, то для лабораторной работы такой вариант можно не учитывать (как мне кажется). Успехов!

Comment: PTRACE_ATTACH позволяет подключить чужой процесс к себе в качестве дочернего.